# Arrays of strings in c it appears (null)

Tags: c, arrays, string, null

well, I have to make this program that asks the user the names and that it inserts it in an array and then print the array, but it doesn't print anything else than null and i don't know what i'm doing wrong, the code is in spanish but the function "insertar" just inserts the new name and listar has to list the items in the array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 5
#include<string.h> 

char arreglo[MAX];
int indice;


//prototipo de funcion
int menu (char texto[],int n);
void insertar (char dato);
void listar();

main(){
//variable locales
    int opcion;
    char dato[50];
    indice = -1;

    do{
        opcion = menu("\n1) Insertar\n2) Borrar\n3) Actualizar\n4) Ordenar\n5) listar\n6) Buscar\n7) Salir\n",7);

        switch(opcion) 
        {
            case 1://insertar 
                if(indice < MAX-1){
                    printf("Dame el dato a insertar");
                    scanf("%s", dato);
                    insertar(dato[50]);
                }//fin if
                else{
                     printf("error no hay espacio" );
                }//fin else
            break;

            case 2:
                 printf("\nBorrar");
            break;

            case 3:
                 printf("\nActualizar");
            break;

            case 4:
                 printf("\nordenar");
            break;

            case 5://listar
                 printf("\nListando\n");
                 listar();
                 printf("%s \t ", arreglo);

            break;

            case 6:
                 printf("\nBuscar");
            break;

            case 7:
                 printf("\nHasta luego...");
            break;
        }//fin switch

    }while(opcion  != 7);
}//finn del main

int menu (char texto[], int n){
   int opcion;
   do{
        printf("%s", texto);
        scanf("%d",&opcion);
        if(opcion <1 || opcion >n){
        printf("error: opcion no valida");
        }//fin del if
   }while(opcion <1 || opcion >n);
return opcion;
}//fin funcion

void insertar (char dato){
    indice ++;

    arreglo[indice]= dato;
}//fin funcion

void listar(){
    char i;
    for(i=0; i<=indice ; i++){
        printf( "%s \t ", arreglo[i]);



    }
    printf("\n");
}//fin funcion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make an array of strings is to use a two-dimensional array of characters. For example instead of

```
#define MAX 5
...
char arreglo[MAX];
...
char dato[50];
```

you would have

```
#define MAX 5
#define MAX_LEN 50
...
char arreglo[MAX][MAX_LEN];
...
char dato[MAX_LEN];
```

The next thing is to change the `scanf` to `scanf("%49s", dato);`. That prevents the user from overflowing the buffer.

The line `insertar(dato[50]);` should be `insertar(dato);` to pass the `dato` array to the function.

Finally, you need to use the `strcpy` function to copy the string into the array.

```
void insertar(char dato[]) {
    indice++;
    strcpy(arreglo[indice], dato);
}
```

And the insertar method declaration should become:

```
void insertar(char dato[]);
```